# Determine the following languages of Σ∗

Tags: formal-languages

For the alphabet Σ = {0, 1}, let A, B, C ⊆ Σ∗ be the languages below.

i. A={1,0,00,11,000,111,0000,1111}

ii. B={w∈Σ∗|||w||≥2}

iii. C = {w ∈ Σ∗|||w|| ≤ 2}

Note: ||w|| denotes the length of the word w.

Determine the following languages of Σ∗:

a. A∩B.

b. A∩C.

c. B∪C.

d. A∆B.

Now what I have so far is,

a) A∩B = {00, 11, 000, 111, 0000, 1111}

b) A∩C = {1, 0, 00, 11}

c) B∪C. = Σ∗

d) A∆B. = the elements that are in A or B but NOT both.

Now first, I wasn't sure if I understood this properly... Second, I wasn't sure if the period symbol actually means anything relevant or if it is just there to act as a period. Third, I wasn't sure how to actually write out the answer for d because there are so many possible values that fit.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think the most elegant way to write (d) is $\Sigma \cup B$. But you can probably write it in any way that conveys that you understand what you're doing and uses correct notation.

And no, the period doesn't have mathematical meaning. It's just a period.

All the answers are correct.

Comment: When you say to write it as Σ∪B , doesn't that include the element 000 which is also in A and as such, is not in the language A∆B because it is both in B and A?

Comment: Ah, you're right, so then use no such trickery.  Perhaps just $A \cup B \setminus \{00,11,000,111,0000,1111\}$.